# synchronization block using different objects

Tags: java, synchronization

Does it really matter if what object we are using to get the lock on the synchronization block.

For eg, i have 2 code fragments as shown below. 
Both produces same output. I have only changed the object used to get lock on the synchronization block

**Code 1:**

```
package test.thread.synchronization;
public class Run1 implements Runnable{
String ts1=null;
public Run1(String ts1){
    this.ts1=ts1;
}
    @Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    run1Print();
}
public  void run1Print(){
    synchronized(ts1){
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("run1Print: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+i);
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

====

```
package test.thread.synchronization;
public class Run2 implements Runnable{
String ts1=null;
public Run2(String ts1){
    this.ts1=ts1;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    run2Print();
}
public void run2Print(){
    synchronized(ts1){
//  System.out.println("Decrement");

    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("run2Print: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+i);
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

=====

```
 package test.thread.synchronization;
 public class Ts1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Ts1 ts1 = new Ts1();
    String ts1 = "";
    Run1 tr1 = new Run1(ts1);
    Run2 tr2 = new Run2(ts1);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(tr1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(tr2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

}

**CODE 2:**

```
package test.thread.synchronization;
public class Run1 implements Runnable{
Ts1 ts1=null;
public Run1(Ts1 ts1){
    this.ts1=ts1;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    run1Print();
}
public  void run1Print(){
    synchronized(ts1){
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("run1Print: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+i);
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

======

```
package test.thread.synchronization;
public class Run2 implements Runnable{
Ts1 ts1=null;
public Run2(Ts1 ts1){
    this.ts1=ts1;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    run2Print();
}
public void run2Print(){
    synchronized(ts1){
//  System.out.println("Decrement");
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("run2Print: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+i);
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

======

```
package test.thread.synchronization;
public class Ts1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Ts1 ts1 = new Ts1();
    //String ts1 = "";
    Run1 tr1 = new Run1(ts1);
    Run2 tr2 = new Run2(ts1);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(tr1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(tr2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}

}
```

Comment: Don't synchronize on a String literal. Use a dedicated, final object as your lock (as in `private final Object lock = new Object();`). String literals are pooled, and `""` is thus a unique object throughout all the code in the VM. If everybody synchronizes on `""`, that's a recipe for deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

The object type doesn't matter, however you ought to synchronize on unique `final` objects or else you might inadvertently have two threads synchronizing on two different objects.